# Can I template the type of a template value parameter?

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose I want to create a struct that converts the value of an enum to a meta int, such as `boost::mpl::int_`. I could do something like this:

```
template <typename Enum, Enum value>
struct Convert
{
  using type = boost::mpl::int_<static_cast<int>(value)>;
};
```

This would work fine, but to call it I'd have to write `Convert<Enum, Enum::VALUE>::type`. Is it possible to write a class so I simply have to write `Convert<Enum::VALUE>::type` to have `Convert` *deduce* the type of `Enum`?

I don't know the type of `Enum`, so `Convert` should be able to take *any* enum. I'd like to avoid macros.

Answer (score 2):

Functions can deduce template parameters; classes cannot. That's why std has functions like `make_pair` as a complement to the `pair` class.

You can use a similar strategy.

For instance, you can declare a templated `Convert` function and then extract its return type via `decltype(Convert<Enum::VALUE>())`.

Comment: But how can I use a function to return a type?

Comment: Well, there's always `decltype`.

Comment: I can't hide that from the user though, I'd essentially be asking the user to decltype a function that can never be called, it's messy but I guess it would work. I was hoping to avoid exposing implementation details like this, so the user would just see a simple metafunction.

Comment: Well, `Convert<Enum::VALUE>::type` is slightly cleaner than `decltype(Convert<Enum::VALUE>())` but it's not as if either one is amazingly elegant and beautiful.